# Re-Captcha Angular CORS Issue

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am using Angular 1.x to POST a verification request to Google's re-captcha as follows:

```
var post_data = {  //prepare payload for request
     'secret':'xxxxx',
     'response':fields.myRecaptchaResponse
};

$http.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', post_data)
```

In my console I can see the following error:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://igs.dev' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.*

I have read multiple answers on Stackoverflow, most seem to suggest adding a plugin to Chrome but that is not a solution for my users who will be using the re-captcha to validate a contact form.

Is this a misconfiguration of my server or is my Angular script missing something? I have already ensured that my domain is configured in my re-captcha account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReCaptcha is validated on the server-side, not the client side. The [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) error is due to the fact that the ReCaptcha API is not meant to be used by a browser.

You need to send your recaptcha data to your API/server which then verifies it is correct by sending a request to the ReCaptcha API. There are no CORS restrictions when servers make HTTP requests to each other.

See this [Tuts tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024) on how the implementation and flow of data works

Comment: Of course, makes sense, the request for verification needs to come from the server not the client. Working nicely now.

Answer (score 3):

The end point `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` is part of server side validation and not the client side. You should hit this endpoint from your server, not from your client (Angular 1.X).

So the flow may look like this:

At your client side (Angular 1.X) you will be loading the re-captcha widget in your html which will perform the validation and store a hash value in a hidden input field which will be sent to your server along with the other form details when user submits the form. Now at your server side you will hit that endpoint to verify if the validation was successful.

Also, in no case you should be storing your secret at the client side. It should always be maintained at your server side for server-to-server communication purposes.

Read the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).